# I ran slowly for 2 seconds for 5 seconds

Tags: sentence-structure

I ran for 5 seconds.

I ran slowly for 2 seconds and fast for 3 seconds.

In this case, is there any grammatical error in “I ran slowly for 2 seconds for 5 seconds”?

Comment: Numbers twelve and under should be spelled out, not Roman numerals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I would say there is a grammatical error but you could look at it that way. In any case the sentence makes no sense and no one will understand what you're trying to say.

You cannot say "I did X activity for [some time] for [another time]." That simply doesn't work, and I don't know why you think it would; the sentence contradicts itself. Would you say that in your native language?

The best way is to be clear about what you actually mean, just like you did: "I ran slowly for two seconds and fast for three seconds."